# Puppeteer screen not vertically centering flexbox item properly

Tags: html, css, puppeteer, vertical-alignment, google-chrome-headless

I am seeing this using [puppeteer-stream](https://github.com/Flam3rboy/puppeteer-stream) to record video (it's a thin 1-file wrapper around puppeteer).

[image]

Notice how it's not centered vertically. There is no scrollable area either, this is it.

The HTML is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 800px;
        width: 800px;
      }

      #content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
      }

      #row {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 32px;
        width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #row * {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        color: #9A7FAE;
      }

      #row .highlight {
        color: #BEE5B0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='content'><div id='row'><span>i am some text</span></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the Puppeteer script is essentially this:

```
const { launch, getStream } = require('puppeteer-stream')

const fs = require('fs')

const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/poem.webm`)

const wait = (ms) => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, ms))

async function start() {
  const browser = await launch({
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [`--window-size=${800},${800}`]
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
  })
  await page.goto('file:///Users/me/poem.html')
  const stream = await getStream(page, { audio: true, video: true })
  await page.click('#row')
  console.log("recording")

  stream.pipe(file).on('end', () => {
    console.log('end')
  })
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await stream.destroy()
    file.close()
    console.log("finished")
    await browser.close()
  }, 1000 * 30)
}

start()
```

Why is it not centering vertically? How do I get it to vertically center?

Comment: Lance, I know this is pretty old, but did you find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: No sorry, I am not sure I ever figured this out, probably just did a hack to align things.